# Making your form input text control have right size fit?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I have a view and im creating a form, but the input text is too big and want a normal input text when user uses his or her title field within a form. Below is my logic but it fits the whole layout and does not look good and im using bootstrap class. Please assist to have normal class for my input text allow user insert normal input text.

```
   <div class="register-box">
               <div class="register-logo">

               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="card">
               <div class="card-body register-card-body">
                   <center>
                       <img src="~/Images/eNtsa.png" />
                   </center>
                   <center>
                       <p><b>Training Course Registration:Motion MasterClass</b></p>
                   </center>

                   @using (Html.BeginForm("editRegForm", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @role = "form" }))
                   {
                       @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                       <div class="input-group-mb-2">
                           @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Title, new {@class = "form-control", type = "text", id = "title", autofocus = "autofocus", placeholder = "Title", required = "required"})
                               <div class="input-group-text">

                               </div>

                       </div>
                   }

               </div>
           </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My work around to this is given as below, basically i wanted to find a way where my form will be on the center including text input of my form.

```
@using eNtsaRegistrationTraining.Models
@model EditTrainingRegFormViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Ttile = "Dashboard";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_HomeLayout.cshtml";
}
<center>
    <div class="register-box ">
        <div class="register-logo">

        </div>

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body register-card-body">
                <center>
                    <img src="~/Images/eNtsa.png" />
                </center>
                <center>
                    <p><b>Training Course Registration:Motion MasterClass</b></p>
                </center>

                @using (Html.BeginForm("editRegForm", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @role = "form" }))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text", id = "title", autofocus = "autofocus", placeholder = "Title", required = "required" })
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <div class="input-group-text">

                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                }

            </div>
        </div>
</center>
           </div>
```